# Split string and still keep the delimiter

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a string of code like this:

```
replace [IntType]
import TYPE [libc_to_basic_type_entry*]
```

Now I want to split them into arrays by using Python regex like this:

```
["replace", "[", "IntType", "]"]
["import", "TYPE", "[", "libc_to_basic_type_entry, "*", "]"]
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.

---

At first, I try to do simple `string.split("[")` and keep looping over the string to `split` with the other characters. But i found that this way is not effective, so I would like to ask for help by using regex.

Comment: At first, I try to do simple string.split("[") and keep looping over the string to split with the other characters. But i found that this way is not effective, so I would like to ask for help by using regex

Comment: It is always better to show your attempts in question. I have edited your question and updated it with your comment. Please fee free to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
\s*(\w+|[^\w\s])\s*
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^\w\s]`: Match a character that is not a word or whitespace character
- `)`: End capture group
- `\s*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces

**Code:**

```sh
s = 'import TYPE [libc_to_basic_type_entry*]'
print (re.findall(r'\s*(\w+|[^\w\s])\s*', s))
```

**Output:**

```
['import', 'TYPE', '[', 'libc_to_basic_type_entry', '*', ']']
```